Free text-to-speech program running on Windows offline?
I'm seeking recommendations of a free text-to-speech program that runs on Windows offline. The supplier must be other than Google or Apple.
The functionality that's at NaturalReaders.com would be fine - i.e. you cut and paste the text in and then click to hear the speech. Ideally I would also like a button enabling saving as an MP3, and no web browser to be involved.

Umm... what about the built-in windows TTS capability?

As far as I'm aware, I do not have the required type of program already on my Windows box.

tortoise-tts is a great choice, Its free, open source, and works offline.
You can check their repo on Github here: https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts

Balabolka fulfills your requirements:

is gratis (freeware, not open-source)
works on windows (I use it on Windows 10, but the website says it supports Windows 11 as well)
works offline
works "cut and paste"
can just play the text in order to listen to the text
can save as WAV and MP3
no web browser needed

However, the problem with typical TTS is not the program, but the voices. Balabolka works with Microsoft SAPI voices and it'll be hard to get good gratis voices. If you compare Microsoft David or Microsoft Zira to what you get from modern AI generated stuff, that's far behind.
The website lists many places where you can get voices. Please note that even if you buy them, you can still not use most of them commercially (AFAIK, last checked ~2019).

Good GitHub repos with >10k stars for offline text-to-speech:

https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts : Apache-2.0 license.
https://github.com/RVC-Boss/GPT-SoVITS : MIT license.
https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS : MPL-2.0 license.

